# Angular JS ng-if with boolean bind expression not working

Tags: angularjs

When i am using ng-if with a flag and list contains some values:

```
 <tr ng-if="flag" ng-repeat="x in list1">
    {{"print a"}}
    <!-- do something -->
</tr>
<tr ng-if="!flag" ng-repeat="x in list2">
    {{"print b"}}
    <!-- do something -->
</tr>
```

It is printing both a and b irrespective of flag.It should only print a and b based on flag value?

Comment: Can u provide more details??

Comment: make a js-fiddle so that we can debug your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go..

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
  .controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.flag = true;
    $scope.list1 = [10,20,30,40,50];
    
    $scope.list2 = [10,20,30,40,50];
    
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <tr ng-if="flag" ng-repeat="x in list1">
    <td>
    {{"print a"}}
    </td>
  </tr>

    <tr ng-if="!flag" ng-repeat="x in list2">
     <td>
       {{"print b"}}
     </td>
  
    </tr>
</table>
```

So, it does work.